# How to detect code on databricks notebook

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, databricks

I would like to create a python function that searches for a specific block of code in the current databricks notebook I run the function in. Is there a way to do this? I haven't found anything that runs trough all the notebook cells and checks if the code exists. Also if it is possible, is there a way to return the cell number?

Example: I want to run a function that detects if there is any cell that starts with "%sql", because I cant have any sql code on the notebook.

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried already? Like, export function of Workspace  API?

Comment: I havent tried anything because i cant find anything that searches trought the databricks cells in search of a specific block of code